# CascadeType Merge is ignored when Persist is set

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hy all

I'm having a hard time solving the following spring jpa problem.
Let's say I have the following simple data model (two entities with a one direction relationship between the two)

```
@Accessors(chain = true) @Getter @Setter  @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}

@Accessors(chain = true) @Getter @Setter  @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;    
}

@Accessors(chain = true) @Getter @Setter  @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Entity2 extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade={ALL})
    private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

and the following plumbing to store them

```
public interface Entity1Dao extends JpaRepository< Entity1, Long >, JpaSpecificationExecutor< Entity1 > {
    
    Entity1 findByName(String name);
}

public interface Entity2Dao extends JpaRepository< Entity2, Long >, JpaSpecificationExecutor< Entity2 > {
    
    Entity2 findByName(String name);    
}

@Service
public class StoreService {

    @Autowired
    Entity1Dao dao1;
    
    @Autowired
    Entity2Dao dao2;
    
    @Transactional
    public Entity1 saveEntity1(Entity1 e) {
        return dao1.save(e);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Entity2 saveEntity2(Entity2 e) {
        return dao2.save(e);
    }

    public Entity1 loadEntity1ByName(String name) {
        return dao1.findByName(name);
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the following test

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(value = MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class JpaDemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    StoreService store;
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(store).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void insertEntity1() {
        store.saveEntity1(new Entity1("test entity1"));
        Entity1 saved = store.loadEntity1ByName("test entity1");
        assertThat(saved).isNotNull().hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties();
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(4)
    void insertEntity2WithNewEntity1() {
        store.saveEntity2(new Entity2("with new entity1", new Entity1("new entity1")));
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(5)
    void insertEntity2WithExistingEntity1() {
        store.saveEntity2(new Entity2("with saved entity1", store.loadEntity1ByName("test entity1")));
    }
}
```

the last test (i.e. insertEntity2WithExistingEntity1) fails with the following exception

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
> persist: com.example.jpaDemo.Entity1

If I change the CascadeType in Entity2 to MERGE, that test passes but the insertEntity2WithNewEntity1 fails with the following exception

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
> unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
> flushing : com.example.jpaDemo.Entity2.entity1 ->
> com.example.jpaDemo.Entity1

I've tried multiple combination of cascading types bute it seems that as soon as PERSIST is used, the last test fails (and ALL includes PERSIST).

I would have expected that if MERGE **and** PERSIST are set, they would both be active but form the test it looks like MERGE is ignored when PERSIST is set.
Any clues, tips, hints at what I'm doing wrong so that both tests run???

**EDIT**

The tests are suppose to mimick the behaviour of a REST service endpoint reveiving and saving json reprensentation of an Entity1.

The json for the third test would be

```
{ name: "with new entity1", entity1: { name: "new entity1"}}
```

The json for the fourth would be

```
{ name: "with new entity1", entity1: { id: 1, version: 0, name: "test entity1"}}
```

JPA should **persists** the entity1 in the third test because it's id is null but should **merge** the one in the fourth test because it's id is *not* null.

I am however unable to do both, it's either one or the other.

**EDIT 2**

I've modified Entity1 slightly to have a reference to the list of Entity2 associated to it and annotated it with @OneToMany and the same cascading type as in Entity2 and it's the same behavior.

When I set the cascading type to MERGE and only Merge, I'm able to save a new entity that has a reference with an existing one but I can't save a new entity with a reference to a new one.

When I set the cascading type to PERSIST (i.e PERSIST on its own, PERSIST and MERGE or ALL), it's the oppposit; I can save a new entity with a reference to anther new entity but I can't save a new entity with a reference to an already existing one.

So it's seem that when PERSIST is set, it overrides the behavior of MERGE. That, to me, is a bug. Is it not?

I've uploaded the source to github in case you want to experiment or take a look at it yourself. https://github.com/willix71/persistVsMerge.git

Comment: I've logged a bug repport at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1771 but nothing yet

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Transactional on your last test. The entity loaded is detached as there is no outer transaction, you can't persist it.

```
@Test
@Order(5)
@Transactional
void insertEntity2WithExistingEntity1() {
    store.saveEntity2(new Entity2("with saved entity1", store.loadEntity1ByName("test entity1")));
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to solve. The @Transactional is placed on the StoreService. I'm trying to find a way to be able to store a "new entity2" linked either with an already existing entity1 or a totally new one but no matter what, the "linking" is done outside of the transaction context.
see my EDIT in the original question

Comment: In this situation, you need to use merge

Comment: Well if I add MERGE (with no PERSIST) the third test (i.e. insertEntity2WithNewEntity1) fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant anymore, but the code below works as I would expect. Removing "cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST" will fail the persist test with "object references an unsaved transient instance".

I also noticed in your github repo that you are attempting to do cascading both from parent to child and child to parent. I think this is the root cause of your issues.

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    Address address;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    List<User> user;
}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
}

public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, UUID> {
}
```

Tests:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Test
    void testMerge() {
        var address = new Address();
        addressRepository.save(address);

        var user = new User();
        user.setAddress(address);
        userRepository.save(user);

        assertThat(userRepository.findAll()).contains(user);
        assertThat(addressRepository.findAll()).contains(address);
    }  

    @Test
    void testPersist() {
        var address = new Address();

        var user = new User();
        user.setAddress(address);
        userRepository.save(user);

        assertThat(userRepository.findAll()).contains(user);
        assertThat(addressRepository.findAll()).contains(address);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Trillo for trying but I can't run your code because I'm missing the DataSourceConfig.

Comment: I think I know why your code works. According to the @DataJpaTest javadoc: "By default, tests annotated with {@code @DataJpaTest} are transactional"; meaning that you are in a transaction the whole time. You will never need to merge your object. I'm trying to save object that are created or linked OUTSIDE the transaction and then merged/persisted when inside the transaction.